# Example of a AggregateRoot and single responsibility principle

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, solid-principles

I am doing a bit of research into DDD, CQRS and ES. Looking at this [source code](https://github.com/MarkNijhof/Fohjin/blob/master/Fohjin.DDD.Example/Fohjin.DDD.Domain/Account/ActiveAccount.cs) of a aggregate root, I am just curious whether this does not violate the single responsibility principle? Or is this to be expected for a aggregate root/DDD? Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to think of SRP is "there must be a single reason for this code to change". If there is more than one reason then we can say it's an SRP violation.

So looking at the code I can see a few reasons it might change:

Additional account information is required to be stored, more than just an account name. Customer services need information to contact the account holder, address, email, phone number.

The memento object deserialization needs to become more complex. At the moment it's only a single pipe `|` separating amount and account:

```
 var split = ledger.Value.Split(new[] { '|' });
```

There's a number of events, `AccountOpenedEvent` `AccountClosedEvent` etc. this class could change if there are more events required in future, e.g. `AccountSuspendedEvent`.

I could probably go on, but yes this class violates SRP in my opinion. Does it need to be changed now? No, probably not, I would hope there is a decent test suite ([this does here](https://github.com/MarkNijhof/Fohjin/blob/master/Fohjin.DDD.Example/Test.Fohjin.DDD/Domain/Repositories/ActiveAccountRepositoryTest.cs)) and just refactor later as a first step before implementing a change.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please suggest a better way of doing it? My idea would be to inject some eventhandler which handles all these events (given the agg root) but then you end up with another class that has tons of methods ...

Comment: I don't think it's that bad. I'd start with something like this and see what I can refactor if anything. Are you doing memento with it? If so, that's the worst thing in my opinion. The `ActiveAccount` having the deserialization code for the ledgers. I'd move that to `ActiveAccountMemento` so it can live along side the serialization code.

Comment: It's very old, perhaps worth asking the author if they would still do it this way. I don't fully understand the reason for the events, so it's hard to comment.

Comment: Thanks! Thought it is a common ddd thing to only change aggregate roots via events/methods (as all data is private). The question is how else can this be handled - where should all these methods go otherwise.

Comment: Could be, I'm not a DDD expert unfortunately. But assuming the events are normal DDD I think the events are the first responsibility of this class and so belong there and you should expect to change the class if the events change. That's SRP. If the ledger changes on the other hand, it's unfortunate that you may need to modify this class because of the deserialization code. I'd move that code elsewhere. The other slight issue was the additional account information; that could be stored in AccountName renamed to reflect it's new job, but I think that refactor can be left till later if required.